# Create and add f:selectItems to HtmlSelectOneRadio programmatically

Tags: jsf, facelets, dynamic-forms

I'm using JSF to create a questionnaire and therefore I need to create my whole xhtml pragmatically because there are different types of questions and the number of them is not predefined.

All I have is a h:panelGrid on my view and the rest is generated in my backing bean.

I have no problem creating HtmlOutputText and HtmlInputText. For that purpose I create them using getApplication e.g. like this:

```
getApplication().createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
```

and then add the component to my grid like this:

```
grid.getChildren().add(questionnumber);
```

where "grid" is my panelGrid element.
So I put my questions in a loop and based on the type of question from the db I decide what type of component to create. If the question is a normal text question I can easily use a HtmlInputText. But I have multiple choice questions too. Therefore I need to create SelectOneRadio menus and add SelectItems in them.

I can create a `HtmlSelectOneRadio` using the same createComponent method that I mentioned above. But I'm unable to add options to it (selectitem components). Is there a way that I can do this? Do we have a UIComponent for this that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution myself. I had to use UISelectItems and add it to my SelectOneMenu like this:

```
final UISelectItem select = (UISelectItem) getApplication().createComponent(UISelectItem.COMPONENT_TYPE);
List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
for (int k = 0; k < options.length; k++){
items.add(new SelectItem(options[k]));                
}
UISelectItems selectItems = new UISelectItems();
selectItems.setValue(items);
selectOneRadio.getChildren().add(selectItems);
 grid.getChildren().add(selectOneRadio);
```